# I cannot hide a textfield and label in my iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

here is the low down:

```
-(IBAction)button1click:(id)sender; 
    {
     label1.hidden=YES;
     textfield1.hidden=YES;
     label2.hidden=NO;
     textfield2.hidden=NO;

-(IBAction)button2click:(id)sender; 
    {
     label1.hidden=NO;
     textfield1.hidden=NO;
     label2.hidden=YES;
     textfield2.hidden=YES;
```

the is issue is that when i first open my screen all 4 labels are visible. By default button1 radio is checked but label2 and textfield 2 are visible when they shouldnt be. if i press button1 even though it is already selected the items with hide and then all is good. My issue is having them hidden when the screen first opens up.

Thanx all for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, in your viewDidLoad method:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self button1click:nil]; //nil or the instance of button1 if you need it
}
```

In this way, you will execute the same code when you press button1 without duplicate your code.

Comment: you're welcome. Don't forget to check the correct answer if you consider your question as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You can take one of two approaches to hide the label.

a) in Interface builder you can click the check box for hidden in the attributes inspector. If you do that the default behavior will always be hidden when the app launches then you can make it visible in code like your example shows

b) add your existing code to hide the label to your view controllers  - (void)viewDidLoad method.

both methods work equally well.

Answer (score 1):

When you create that objects you can set foo.isHidden = YES